# Adding dynamic attribute to python class fails

Tags: python, dynamic, attributes

I'm trying to dynamically add an attribute to some class from [javalang](https://github.com/c2nes/javalang):

```
In [1]: import javalang
In [2]: tree = javalang.parse.parse("class A { B c = ddd.doSomething(); }")
In [3]: print(tree.types[0].body[0].declarators[0].initializer)
MethodInvocation(arguments=[], member=doSomething, postfix_operators=[], prefix_operators=[], qualifier=ddd, selectors=[], type_arguments=None)
```

But when I try to simply assign a new attribute (`qualifier_type`)

```
In [4]: tree.types[0].body[0].declarators[0].initializer.qualifier_type = "DDD"
```

Nothing happens:

```
In [5]: print(tree.types[0].body[0].declarators[0].initializer)
MethodInvocation(arguments=[], member=doSomething, postfix_operators=[], prefix_operators=[], qualifier=ddd, selectors=[], type_arguments=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, **my attribute was there all the time**, it just wasn't printed, since the [`__repr__`](https://github.com/c2nes/javalang/blob/566963547575e93d305871d9cb26ce47ff1a036e/javalang/ast.py#L46) implementation iterated over `self.attrs`.

```
In [1]: import javalang
In [2]: tree = javalang.parse.parse("class A { B c = ddd.doSomething(); }")
In [3]: tree.types[0].body[0].declarators[0].initializer.qualifier_type = "DDD"
In [4]: print(tree.types[0].body[0].declarators[0].initializer.qualifier_type)
DDD
```

Explicitly adding my attribute, I can now print my class (scroll to the right to see it)

```
In [5]: tree.types[0].body[0].declarators[0].initializer.attrs += ("qualifier_type",)
In [6]: print(tree.types[0].body[0].declarators[0].initializer)
MethodInvocation(arguments=[], member=doSomething, postfix_operators=[], prefix_operators=[], qualifier=ddd, qualifier_type=DDD, selectors=[], type_arguments=None)
```